# Deactivate checkbox if a condition in a text input is true in javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I've several text inputs and an checkbox array.
If the value of the text input is less than 6 deactivate the checkbox.
I tried this but the checkbox is always enabled.

```
<script>
    function desactivacasillas() {
        var formularioprincipal = document.getElementById("troncocomun");
        var primerelemento = document.getElementById("1").value;

        if (document.getElementById("1").value < 6) {
            var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap id="materia">ALGEBRA</td>
        <td>5.62</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="1" name="1" onkeydown="return validarnumero(event)" onkeypress="return compruebacampo(event,this)" onkeyup="desactivacasillas(event)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox1" value="0">
            <input type="checkbox" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox1" value="5.62">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can you tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to disable the hidden element. IDs must be **unique**!

Comment: Why are you using inline events (I'm not saying it is causing the problem)

Comment: what do you mean with inline events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>



 <script>
 function desactivacasillas(args) {



 if (document.getElementById("1").value.length < 6) {
 $("#checkbox2").attr("disabled", true);
 }
 else
 {
 $("#checkbox2").attr("disabled", false);
 }
}
</script>
<table>
 <tr>
 <td nowrap id="materia">ALGEBRA</td>
 <td>5.62</td>
 <td>
     <input type="text" id="1" name="1" onkeyup="desactivacasillas(this.value)">
 </td>
 <td>
     <input type="hidden" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox1" value="0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox2" value="5.62">
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>


   </body>
 </html>
```

Feel free to ask anything if you don't understand the above program.

Comment: sorry but the checkbox still enabled .

Comment: Have you changed the id of the checkbox1 to checkbox2 whose value is 5.62?Do I thing take this link [http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_myfirst] and copy and paste my whole code there it is working I have tried it.Maybe your onkeydown and onkeypress functions not working.

Comment: yes I've changed the id of the checkbox,the link is not working.

Comment: @user3504980 Show me your updated code and try this link to copy paste my code http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_intro_inner_html

Comment: great it works!,only 1 question. How can i enable the checkbox if the input text value is equal or greater than 6?

Comment: @user3504980 I have already wrote the code for that in my program when your value becomes above 6 the `else` part of function works and box becomes visible.Please accept my answer if you got the solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks men you are awesome!!,only change the ".value.length" to ".value" THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @user3504980 man `value.length` is working in my case when you will change `value.length` to only `value` it won't work?

Comment: well i just want the value not the length.anyway thanks!

Comment: Why are you using jQuery if the op doesn't seem to use it? And you shouldn't booleans to `.attr`.

Comment: @FelixKling Firstly I gave him the javascript answer but he was unable to run it so I gave him the JQuery way of doing it.He was just concerned with the output not with the implementation(Javascript or JQuery).He didn't complain with JQuery. BTW you posted `you shouldn't booleans to .attr` . Could you please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Make the IDs unique. Here is the below I tried and worked

```
<script>
    function desactivacasillas() {
        var formularioprincipal = document.getElementById("troncocomun");
        var primerelemento = document.getElementById("1").value;

        if (document.getElementById("1").value < 6) {
            var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("checkbox2");
           checkbox1.disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap id="materia">ALGEBRA</td>
        <td>5.62</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="1" name="1" value="6" onkeydown="return 

validarnumero(event)" onkeypress="return compruebacampo(event,this)" 

onkeyup="desactivacasillas(event)">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox1" value="0">
            <input type="checkbox" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox2" value="5.62">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry but the checkbox still enabled  even if I write a lower value of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use on load function in java script to disable check box while loading. and use parse Int function because input returns value as string.

change the ID's of check boxes. ID's are always Unique.

```
<script>
    function disableCheckbox(){
        document.getElementById("checkbox2").disabled = true;
    }
    function desactivacasillas() {
        var formularioprincipal = document.getElementById("troncocomun");
        var primerelemento = document.getElementById("1").value;
        if (parseInt(document.getElementById("1").value,10) > 6) {
            document.getElementById("checkbox2").disabled = false;
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="disableCheckbox();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td nowrap id="materia">ALGEBRA</td>
            <td>5.62</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="1" name="1" onkeyup="desactivacasillas(event)">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox1" value="0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="carga[0]" id="checkbox2" value="5.62">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```